# In AMPL, how to refer to part of the result, and use them in multiple places

Tags: ampl

I'm learning AMPL to speed up a model currently in excel spreadsheet with excel solver. It basically based on the matrix multiplication result of a 1 x m variables and an m x n parameters. And it would find the variables to maximize the minimum of certain values in the result while keeping some other values in the same result satisfying a few constraints. How to do so in AMPL?

```
Given: P= m x n parameters
Variable: X= 1 x m variable we tried to solve
Calculate: R= X x P , result of matrix multiplication of X and P
Maximize: min(R[1..3]), the minimum value of the first 3 values in the result
Subject to: R[2]<R[4]
            min(R[6..8])>20
            R[5]-20>R[7]
            X are all integers
```

I read several tutorials and look up the manual but can't find the solution to this seemingly straightforward problem. All I found is maximize a single value, which is the calculation result. And it was used only once and does not appear again in the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach for "maximize the minimum" problems in products like AMPL is to define an auxiliary variable and set linear constraints that effectively define it as the minimum, converting a nonlinear function (min) into linear rules.

For instance, suppose I have a bunch of decision variables `x[i]` with `i` ranging over an index set `S`, and I want to maximize the minimum over `x[i]`. AMPL syntax for that would be:

```
var x_min;
s.t. DefineMinimum{i in S}: x_min <= x[i];
maximize ObjectiveFunction: x_min;
```

The constraint only requires that `x_min` be less than or equal to the minimum of `x[i]`. However, since you're trying to maximize `x_min` and there are no other constraints on it, it should always end up exactly equal to that minimum (give or take machine-arithmetic epsilon considerations).

If you have `parameters` (i.e. values are known before you run the optimisation) and want to refer to their minimum, AMPL lets you do that more directly:

```
param p_min := min{j in IndexSet_P} p[j];
```

While AMPL also supports this syntax for variables, not all of the solvers used with AMPL are capable of accepting this type of constraint. For instance:

```
reset;
option solver gecode;
set S := {1,2,3};
var x{S} integer;
var x_min = min{s in S} x[s];
minimize OF: sum{s in S} x[s];
s.t. c1: x_min >= 5;
solve;
```

This will run and do what you'd expect it to do, because Gecode is programmed to recognise and deal with min-type constraints. However, if you switch the solver option to `gurobi` or `cplex` it will fail, since these only accept linear or quadratic constraints. To apply a minimum constraint with those solvers, you need to use something like the linearization trick I discussed above.

Comment: can we do like: var x_min=min{i in S}x[i];

Comment: @jerron depends what solver you're using - see update to my answer.